# ¿Como llamar un StartActivityForResult desde un FrameLayout para abrir el diálogo para reconocimiento de voz:?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-intent

Quiero llamar hacer un `Intent` con activity result para reconocer la voz dentro de un `Framelayout`, el `codigo` del reconocimiento de voz funciona bien fuera del `Framelayout`, si lo hago en el `MainActivity`, pero quiero que este dentro del `Framelayout`.

Si lo pongo en el `Framelayout` acaba o en crash o sin hacer nada. ¿A alguien se lo ocurre algo?

Este es el código del `Intent` para el reconocimiento de voz:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
                    if (mContext instanceof Activity) {
                        ((Activity) mContext).startActivityForResult(intent, 10);
                    }
```

Este es el código del `FrameLayout` :

```
public class MaterialSearchView extends FrameLayout{

    private MenuItem mMenuItem;
    private boolean mIsSearchOpen = false;

    //Views
    private View mSearchLayout;


    private SearchViewListener mSearchViewListener;


    private SavedState mSavedState;

    private Button bt;



    private Context mContext;

    public MaterialSearchView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public MaterialSearchView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public MaterialSearchView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs);

        mContext = context;

        initiateView();

    }


    private void initiateView() {
        LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.sv, this, true);
        mSearchLayout = findViewById(R.id.search_layout);
        bt = mSearchLayout.findViewById(R.id.btv);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
                if (mContext instanceof Activity) {
                    ((Activity) mContext).startActivityForResult(intent, 10);
                }

            }
        });


    }


public void setMenuItem(MenuItem menuItem) {
    this.mMenuItem = menuItem;
    mMenuItem.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            showSearch();
            return true;
        }
    });
}


public boolean isSearchOpen() {
    return mIsSearchOpen;
}

public void showSearch() {
    showSearch(true);
}


public void showSearch(boolean animate) {
    if (isSearchOpen()) {
        return;
    }
        mSearchLayout.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        if (mSearchViewListener != null) {
            mSearchViewListener.onSearchViewShown();
        }

    mIsSearchOpen = true;
}


public void closeSearch() {
    if (!isSearchOpen()) {
        return;
    }

    clearFocus();

    mSearchLayout.setVisibility(GONE);
    if (mSearchViewListener != null) {
        mSearchViewListener.onSearchViewClosed();
    }
    mIsSearchOpen = false;

}


public void setOnSearchViewListener(SearchViewListener listener) {
    mSearchViewListener = listener;
}







@Override
public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
    Parcelable superState = super.onSaveInstanceState();

    mSavedState = new SavedState(superState);
    mSavedState.isSearchOpen = this.mIsSearchOpen;

    return mSavedState;
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
    if (!(state instanceof SavedState)) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
        return;
    }

    mSavedState = (SavedState) state;

    if (mSavedState.isSearchOpen) {
        showSearch(false);
    }

    super.onRestoreInstanceState(mSavedState.getSuperState());
}

static class SavedState extends BaseSavedState {
    String query;
    boolean isSearchOpen;

    SavedState(Parcelable superState) {
        super(superState);
    }

    private SavedState(Parcel in) {
        super(in);
        this.query = in.readString();
        this.isSearchOpen = in.readInt() == 1;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
        super.writeToParcel(out, flags);
        out.writeString(query);
        out.writeInt(isSearchOpen ? 1 : 0);
    }

    //required field that makes Parcelables from a Parcel
    public static final Creator<SavedState> CREATOR =
            new Creator<SavedState>() {
                public SavedState createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                    return new SavedState(in);
                }

                public SavedState[] newArray(int size) {
                    return new SavedState[size];
                }
            };
}

public interface OnQueryTextListener {

    /**
     * Called when the user submits the query. This could be due to a key press on the
     * keyboard or due to pressing a submit button.
     * The listener can override the standard behavior by returning true
     * to indicate that it has handled the submit request. Otherwise return false to
     * let the SearchView handle the submission by launching any associated intent.
     *
     * @param query the query text that is to be submitted
     * @return true if the query has been handled by the listener, false to let the
     * SearchView perform the default action.
     */
    boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query);

    /**
     * Called when the query text is changed by the user.
     *
     * @param newText the new content of the query text field.
     * @return false if the SearchView should perform the default action of showing any
     * suggestions if available, true if the action was handled by the listener.
     */
    boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText);
}

public interface SearchViewListener {
    void onSearchViewShown();

    void onSearchViewClosed();
}


}
```

Y este el activityresult del main activity

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case 10:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                    ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                    tv.setText(result.get(0));
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Es importante agregues el mensaje del LogCat, eso ayuda a la comunidad a saber cual es el problema y por si alguien tiene el mismo problema, saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Veo que al instanciar la clase `MaterialSearchView`, recibes el contexto, asigna este contexto a tu variable `mContext`, pero **es importante que el contexto que envíes a la clase `MaterialSearchView`  sea el de la `Activity`** :

```
  private Context mContext;
  ...
  ...
  public MaterialSearchView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
        mContext = context;
    }

    public MaterialSearchView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
        mContext = context;
    }

    public MaterialSearchView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs);    
        mContext = context;    
        initiateView();

    }
```

En tu `OnClickListener` solo asigna este valor del contexto para iniciar el `Intent` mediante `startActivityForResult()` :

```
bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
                /*if (mContext instanceof Activity) {
                    ((Activity) mContext).startActivityForResult(intent, 10);
                }*/
                mContext.startActivityForResult(intent, 10);

            }
        });
```

de esta forma podrás abrir sin problema el diálogo de reconocimiento de voz:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

¡Saludos!. En vez de dejar que tu clase **MaterialSearchView** maneje internamente un onClickListener en el **Button** por qué mejor no proveer un **View.OnClickListener** a dicha clase, e implementar dicho listener en la actividad que utilizas dicho FrameLayout.

Lo que propongo se vería de la siguiente manera:

```
public class MaterialSearchView extends FrameLayout{

//...
private Button bt;
private View.OnClickListener myOnClickListener;

//crear un metodo para setear dicho listener
 public void setOnCLickListener(listener){
      this.myOnClickListener = listener;
 }
```

Luego lo asignar ese listener al botón

```
bt.setOnClickListener(this.myOnClickListener);
```

Comment: Tambien lo probe con un View.OnClickListener, pero ese no es el problema amigo, la cosa es que cuando lanzo el intent con el Start Activity For Result la aplicacion crashea. Lo que quiero saber es como lanzar el intent y el startactivity desder la clase MaterialSearchView que es un framelayout y que el MainActivity lo reciba. Gracias!